# google indexing wrong page

Tags: indexing

When I google for cms tutorial my website is the first link which is obviously great. Unfortunatly it is showing the Under construction title I was using when I was updating my site. When you click on the link you of course you go to my website but the title link still remains "CMS TUTORIAL SITE - Under construction" in google instead of the name of the actual page.

How can I request google to re-index that page, I allready requested to remove the cache for that url with the google webmaster tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could request to update your url [here](http://www.google.com/addurl/?continue=/addurl).